# Question about $\mathbb{Z}^2 \otimes \text{sym}^2\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, symmetric-matrices

I am confused about the set $\mathbb{Z}^2 \otimes \text{sym}^2\mathbb{Z}^3$... Could someone please explain me why this corresponds to the set of pairs of symmetric $3$ by $3$ matrices? Thank you!

Comment: What does $\text{sym}^2\mathbb{Z}^3$ mean here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The second symmetric power, presumably.

Comment: @AlexProvost as in $\wedge^2 \Bbb Z^3$, where $x \wedge y = - y \wedge x$?

Comment: That being the case, it seems clear to me that both of these are free modules with dimension $6$.  I don't know if there's a more natural "correspondence" here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No; instead of dividing the tensor algebra by the ideal generated by $x \otimes x$, we take the ideal generated by $x \otimes y - y \otimes x$. The dimension also happens to be $\binom{3+2-1}{2} = 6$ this way!

Comment: @AlexProvost Oh, sorry, that should be $\vee^2$ then.  I think that's what I really meant?  Thanks

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is $\bigvee V$ notation for the symmetric algebra on a vector space (or free module) $V$? I don't recall seeing that before!

Comment: Well, it's used in some contexts, e.g. in the matrix analysis context.  That's the notation I'm used to, anyway.  Means the same as Sym apparently.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, now that I think about it, it's actually $\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{Z}^4$ that has dimension $6$.

Comment: I get it now! Thank you very much for all the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard basis for $S^2(\mathbb{Z}^3)$ is given by $(e_1e_1,e_1e_2,e_1e_3,e_2e_2,e_2e_3,e_3e_3)$, where juxtaposition denotes the symmetric product and $(e_i)_{i=1}^3$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{Z}^3$. A symmetric integral $3 \times 3$ matrix is uniquely determined by $6$ integer entries which lie on the coordinates $(1,1),(1,2)(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3)$; therefore it is natural to identify the basis vector $e_ie_j$ with the basis matrix which has a single one in the $(i,j)$ position.

Finally, under this identification, the space of pairs of such matrices is $S^2(\mathbb{Z}^3) \oplus S^2(\mathbb{Z}^3) = \mathbb{Z}^2 \otimes S^2(\mathbb{Z}^3)$.